# What does "hence the Greek tradition of the "law-giver", which has captured the imaginations of scholars like Goody." mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In Athens, the early development of a written law code was
>   retrospectively mythologized as the critical factor in breaking the
>   power monopoly of the old aristocracy: hence the Greek tradition of
>   the "law-giver", which has captured the imaginations of scholars like
>   Goody.

I don't understand the part from "hence" to the end. Could someone explain what that part means and modifies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hence" can be reworded (in this case) as something along the lines of "because of this, we have". So, the rest of your sentence basically says that, because "the early development of a written law code was retrospectively mythologized as the critical factor in breaking the power monopoly of the old aristocracy", we have "the Greek tradition of the "law-giver", which has captured the imaginations of scholars like Goody."